# Storing each character of each string of an array into a new 2d array

Tags: javascript

I intend to split a string into a 2d array in javascript in the format of [[],[],[]...] with each word corresponding to each index of the outer array and each letter of each word corresponding to indices of inner arrays and log the contents of the arrays into the console. The code is below:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var str_to_words=str.split(" ");
    var str_to_letters;
    for(var i=0;i<str_to_words.length;i++)
    {
        str_to_letters[i]=str_to_words[i].split();

    }
    return str_to_letters;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

But I get an error : "script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" Can anyone please help? I am new to javascript syntax.

Comment: You have to initialize `str_to_letters`: `var str_to_letters = [];`

Comment: I'm sorry, but doing so, only logs "[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]" into the console, which on expansion displays only each of the words and doesn't separate them into letters. For example when I return str_to_letters[2][1] it just displays "undefined" but I expected that it should print the letter "i" of the word "little".

Comment: You're misinterpreting the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing is **.split('');**
Split without nothing returns string but split supplied with empty string returns array with characters.

So

```
'abc'.split() => 'abc'
```

but

```
'abc'.split('') => ['a','b','c']
```

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    var str_to_words=str.split(" ");
    var str_to_letters = [];
    var res = [];
    for(var i=0;i<str_to_words.length;i++)
    {
        str_to_letters[i]=str_to_words[i].split('');

    }
    return str_to_letters;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: That was my mistake. Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define str_to_letters as array : var str_to_letters = [];

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var str_to_words=str.split(" ");
    var str_to_letters = [];
    for(var i=0;i<str_to_words.length;i++)
    {
        str_to_letters[i]=str_to_words[i].split();

    }
    return str_to_letters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript,  a var will be initially considered as object (key,  value)  pair.

So in order to denote that var is an array,  you have to declare it explicitly.

```
var str_to_letters = new Array();
```

or

```
var str_to_letters = [];
```

A Split method without parameter just returns the complete Statement as result.

So you have to specify **split('') ;**

So fixed working code is a follows

```
function titleCase(str) { 
var str_to_words=str.split(" "); 
var str_to_letters=[]; 
for(var i=0;i<str_to_words.length;i++) 
{ 
str_to_letters[i]=str_to_words[i].split(''); 
} 
return str_to_letters; 
} 
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidsekar/zL9mf7ss/2/

Comment: Can you tell me how I can access each individual letters of the string using this code? It seems like returning (for example) str_to_letters[0][0] doesn't return the individual characters.

Comment: Have updated my solution to reflect the changes for your query

Comment: Thank you for your help.